# Intercepting http-cookies sent from node server in my reactjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, httpcookie

I'm currently trying to send the access & refresh tokens to the frontend using http-cookies , and trying to get them in reactjs and store values in react context after logging in , but i do not get cookie in headers or any other way in front end.

Here is my node code :-

```
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      { username },
      process.env.SECRET_KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      {
        expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION.toString(),
      }
    );

    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
      { username },
      process.env.SECRET_KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN,
      {
        expiresIn: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION.toString(),
      }
    );

    response.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false, 
      sameSite: "strict", 
      maxAge: 1 * 60 * 1000,
    });
    response.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false, 
      sameSite: "strict", 
      maxAge: 2 * 60 * 1000, 
    });

    // *Return the response data
    return response.json({ message: "Login Successful", authenticated: true });
```

Here is my reactjs code:-

```
const sendRequest = async (payload) => {
 let { username, password } = payload;
    const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${API_URL}/api/auth/login`,
        {
          username,
          password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      console.log(response.headers); 
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Server Error:", error.response.data);
        return { error: error.response.data };
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.error("Network Error:", error.request);
        return { error: "Network Error" };
      } else {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
        return { error: "Error" };
      }
    }
}
```

I tried using postman, here are the screenshots
[image]

[image]

Is there any way I can access those cookies in my code ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `httpOnly: true` can not be accessed by javascript on the client (browser) - that's the point of `httpOnly` cookies - read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)

Comment: This approach with a refresh token that's also a JWT makes almost no sense, and would be no better than not having a refresh token and just have a later-expiring access token. I _strongly_ recommend using something that already exists instead of inventing your own insecure authentication system.

Comment: Sharing this once again because it seems appropriate here too: https://evertpot.com/jwt-is-a-bad-default/

Comment: is the cookie have [httponly flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)? if yes, thats the problem.